# Adjusting ContentView size using SnapKit

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uikit, snapkit

When using Auto Layout my code would look like this:

```
    let safeAreaLayoutGuide = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
                
    let bottomAnchor = userImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)
    bottomAnchor.priority = .required - 1
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                userImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
                userImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor
                                                   , constant: 16),
                userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
                userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
                
                userName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
                userName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
                userName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            
                userStatus.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userName.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
                userStatus.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
                userStatus.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
    
                textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userName.bottomAnchor, constant: 48),
                textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
                textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
                textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            
                showStatusButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
                showStatusButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
                showStatusButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
                
                bottomAnchor
            ])
```

The `bottomAnchor` constraint is made to let `contentView` adjust to its content size. Now I'm trying to make the same UI but now using `SnapKit`. Here are the constraints for all the objects on the `contentView`:

```
    userImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.top).offset(16)
                make.left.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.left).offset(16)
                make.height.width.equalTo(userImage.layer.cornerRadius * 2)
            }
            
            userName.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.top).offset(16)
                make.left.equalTo(userImage.snp.right).offset(16)
                make.right.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.right).inset(-16)
            }
            
            userStatus.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(userName.snp.bottom).offset(16)
                make.left.equalTo(userImage.snp.right).offset(16)
                make.right.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.right).offset(-16)
            }
            
            textField.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(userStatus.snp.bottom).offset(40)
                make.left.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.left).offset(16)
                make.right.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.right).offset(-16)
                make.height.equalTo(32)
            }
            
            showStatusButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(textField.snp.bottom).offset(16)
                make.left.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.left).offset(16)
                make.right.equalTo(self.safeAreaInsets.right).offset(-16)
            }
```

I can't figure out what to replace my `bottomAnchor` constraint with. How do I make contentView adjust to what I have? (or basically position it relative to bottom anchor of `showStatusButton`.

Just in case, the whole project is [here](https://github.com/lord-anonymoose/social-media-app/tree/develop) and the file I'm changing is `ProfileHeadevView.swift`

Comment: First, if you know how to use constraints, why switch to SnapKit? Second, simplify... it's a bit much to ask someone to download your project and try to figure out what's what. Third, is your question really just how to set constraint priority with SnapKit?

Comment: Hey @DonMag 1) For educational purpose 2) I’m not pushing anyone to download and review the whole project. All the necessary code is provided in the question itself, GitHub link is provided just in case anybody needs more context 3) I basically need to adjust contentView size using SnapKit and don’t know how to do it yet. contentView bottom anchor should be x points lower than showStatusButton bottom anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to set constraints to `self.safeAreaInsets`, set them to the `contentView` itself...

Here is your original `ProfileHeaderView` - using `NSLayoutConstraints` - with a couple edits since I don't have your `me.login` / `textColor` / `accentColor` / etc:

```
class ContraintsProfileHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    public var user: String = "User" {
        didSet {
            userName.text = user
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Subviews
    
    private var statusText: String = ""
    
    lazy var userImage: UIImageView = {
//      let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: me.login))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ProfilePicture"))
        
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 45
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private lazy var userName: UILabel = {
        let userName = UILabel()
        
        userName.text = "User Name" //me.login
        userName.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
        userName.textColor = .red // textColor
        userName.sizeToFit()
        
        userName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return userName
    }()
    
    private lazy var userStatus: UILabel = {
        let userStatus = UILabel()
        
        userStatus.text = "Waiting for something..."
        userStatus.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
        userStatus.textColor = .gray
        userStatus.sizeToFit()
        userStatus.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        userStatus.textAlignment = .left
        
        userStatus.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return userStatus
    }()
    
    private lazy var showStatusButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue // accentColor
        
        button.setTitle("Set status", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var textField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        
        textField.placeholder = "Hello, world"
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        textField.textColor = .black
        
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(statusTextChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        return textField
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
        changeBackgroundColor()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userStatus.text = statusText
    }
    
    @objc func statusTextChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let text = textField.text {
            statusText = text
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
        changeBackgroundColor()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private
    
    func changeBackgroundColor() {
#if DEBUG
        contentView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
#else
        contentView.backgroundColor = secondaryColor
#endif
    }
    
    private func addSuviews() {
        contentView.addSubview(userImage)
        contentView.addSubview(userName)
        contentView.addSubview(userStatus)
        contentView.addSubview(textField)
        contentView.addSubview(showStatusButton)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        
        let safeAreaLayoutGuide = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        let bottomAnchor = showStatusButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)
        bottomAnchor.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            userImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            userImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor
                                               , constant: 16),
            userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
            userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
            
            userName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            userName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            userName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            userStatus.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userName.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            userStatus.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            userStatus.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userName.bottomAnchor, constant: 48),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            
            showStatusButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            showStatusButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            showStatusButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            bottomAnchor
        ])
    }
}
```

Here's that same `ProfileHeaderView`, but using SnapKit for the constraints:

```
class SnapsProfileHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    public var user: String = "User" {
        didSet {
            userName.text = user
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Subviews
    
    private var statusText: String = ""
    
    lazy var userImage: UIImageView = {
        //      let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: me.login))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ProfilePicture"))
        
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 45
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private lazy var userName: UILabel = {
        let userName = UILabel()
        
        userName.text = "User Name" //me.login
        userName.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
        userName.textColor = .red // textColor
        userName.sizeToFit()
        
        userName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return userName
    }()
    
    private lazy var userStatus: UILabel = {
        let userStatus = UILabel()
        
        userStatus.text = "Waiting for something..."
        userStatus.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
        userStatus.textColor = .gray
        userStatus.sizeToFit()
        userStatus.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        userStatus.textAlignment = .left
        
        userStatus.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return userStatus
    }()
    
    private lazy var showStatusButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue // accentColor
        
        button.setTitle("Set status", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var textField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        
        textField.placeholder = "Hello, world"
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        textField.textColor = .black
        
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(statusTextChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        return textField
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
        changeBackgroundColor()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userStatus.text = statusText
    }
    
    @objc func statusTextChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let text = textField.text {
            statusText = text
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
        changeBackgroundColor()
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private
    
    func changeBackgroundColor() {
#if DEBUG
        contentView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
#else
        contentView.backgroundColor = secondaryColor
#endif
    }
    
    private func addSuviews() {
        contentView.addSubview(userImage)
        contentView.addSubview(userName)
        contentView.addSubview(userStatus)
        contentView.addSubview(textField)
        contentView.addSubview(showStatusButton)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        
        let g = contentView
        
        userImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(g.snp.top).offset(16)
            make.left.equalTo(g.snp.left).offset(16)
            make.height.width.equalTo(userImage.layer.cornerRadius * 2)
        }
        
        userName.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(g.snp.top).offset(16)
            make.left.equalTo(userImage.snp.right).offset(16)
            make.right.equalTo(g.snp.right).inset(-16)
        }
        
        userStatus.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(userName.snp.bottom).offset(16)
            make.left.equalTo(userImage.snp.right).offset(16)
            make.right.equalTo(g.snp.right).offset(-16)
        }
        
        textField.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(userName.snp.bottom).offset(48)
            make.left.equalTo(userImage.snp.right).offset(16)
            make.right.equalTo(g.snp.right).offset(-16)
            make.height.equalTo(32)
        }
        
        showStatusButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(textField.snp.bottom).offset(16)
            make.left.equalTo(g.snp.left).offset(16)
            make.right.equalTo(g.snp.right).offset(-16)
            
            make.bottom.equalTo(g.snp.bottom).offset(-16)
        }
        
    }
}
```

and here's a sample view controller that puts one table view using `ContraintsProfileHeaderView` above a second table view that uses `SnapsProfileHeaderView`:

```
class ProTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let tb1 = UITableView()
    let tb2 = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        [tb1, tb2].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
            v.dataSource = self
            v.delegate = self
            v.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        }

        tb1.register(ContraintsProfileHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "chv")
        tb2.register(SnapsProfileHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "shv")

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        tb1.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalTo(g).inset(20.0)
            make.height.equalTo(300.0)
        }
        tb2.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(tb1.snp.bottom).offset(20.0)
            make.leading.trailing.equalTo(g).inset(20.0)
            make.height.equalTo(300.0)
        }

    }
    
}

extension ProTestVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        return c
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0, tableView == tb1 {
            if let v = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "chv") as? ContraintsProfileHeaderView {
                v.user = "Constraints"
                return v
            }
        }
        if section == 0, tableView == tb2 {
            if let v = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "shv") as? SnapsProfileHeaderView {
                v.user = "SnapKit"
                return v
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

Worth noting: you may want to make use of the `contentView.layoutMarginsGuide` - [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/3622483-layoutmarginsguide) - to get the "recommended amount of padding for content inside of a view"

---

**Edit**

When UIKit lays out the table view elements - header / footer / section header/footers / etc - it is possible, in fact usual, that multiple auto-layout "passes" are made to calculate the framing.

If all the cells use the default cell height, we don't get the constraint warning/error messages for ***its*** layout.

If some of the cells are NOT the default height, auto-layout initially sets the section header height to its default of `17.6667-points` (on a @3x device)... which causes constraint conflicts... then re-process the layout and adjusts the header height.

We often see this in dynamic tableview cells on their own (particularly when multiline labels are embedded in vertical stack views).

By setting the **priority** on the bottom constraint to less-than-required, we tell auto-layout to go ahead and break that constraint if necessary, and not complain about it.

That's why the common "fix" is to use:

```
let bottomAnchor = showStatusButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)
bottomAnchor.priority = .required - 1
bottomAnchor.isActive = true
```

and we no longer see the messages.

If you want to do that with SnapKit, add the priority modifier:

```
make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.snp.bottom).offset(-16).priority(999)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DonMag ! I played around with your code example, applied it to my project and the view is shown just fine - as it is supposed to be. Yet I get a warning `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints...` and a list of constraints. One of those is `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002175540 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' _UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x10bb22960.height == 17.6667 (active)>`. But I didn't set it neither in ViewController nor in UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

Comment: I also see you're setting TableView's height in ViewController using SnapKit (`make.height.equalTo(300.0)`). Could it be a reason you're not getting a warning that I mentioned?

Comment: @Philipp - I tried pulling your GitHub repo, but couldn't get it to build. Grabbed the `ProfileViewController ` and made necessary changes to get it to run (for example, changing this `UITableView().feedView(isHeaderHidden: true)` to `UITableView()`, added plain `PhotosTableViewCell` and `PostViewCell` cells, etc) ... and I do NOT get any auto-layout warnings.

Comment: @Philipp - by the way, the only reason I used SnapKit for the table view constraints was because that's what you're trying to learn. It would have no effect on the layout warning/error you're getting.

Comment: @Philipp - I got your repo to compile and run... see the **Edit** to my answer. As a side note, in your `ProfileViewController` you are registering Photos and Posts cells for reuse, but then in `cellForRowAt` you are **not** dequeueing and reusing them.

Comment: thank you so much for putting truly much effort into solving my problem! I really appreciate it! Adding priority modifier did help indeed. I'll also review your note on dequeueing and reusing Photos and Posts :)