# Passing a variable into custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

There's a `UIViewController` containing `UITableView`.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var profileView: ProfileHeaderView = {
        let profileView = ProfileHeaderView()
        return profileView
    }()
    
    private lazy var feedView: UITableView = {
        let feedView = UITableView().feedView(isHeaderHidden: true)
        feedView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        feedView.allowsSelection = true
        return feedView
    }()
...
}
```

In this `UITableView` there's a custom header (custom class `ProfileHeaderView` conforms to protocol `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`), which is implemented this way:

```
extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {
            if let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView") as? ProfileHeaderView {
                view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                return view
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Let's say our `ProfileHeaderView` has a variable (e.g. a string). How to pass the value for this variable from our `UIViewController` into our custom header?

**Edit** Here's a quick glance on `ProfileHeaderView` declaration:

```
class ProfileHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        
    public var statusText: String?
    
     override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
        changeBackgroundColor()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
        changeBackgroundColor()
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your `ProfileHeaderView` needs a property that you can set. Do you have such a property?

Comment: @HangarRash yep, I add it in `ProfileHeaderView` declaration via optional public var

Comment: can't you set it on:  if let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView") as? ProfileHeaderView {
view. statusText = "every status you want"
            ?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar I tried to do so. My code compiles yet the value does not change to what I set it in `UIViewController`. Maybe I should update something in `init()` of a `ProfileHeaderView` (edited my question and added some more code on it)

Comment: if statusText should set to a label or everything you want, you should set property observer for statusText such as: var statusText: String? {
        didSet { yourlabel.text = statusText }
    }

Comment: Thank you @MaziarSaadatfar . Didn't think of a property observer. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign a value to `statusText`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        if let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView") as? ProfileHeaderView {
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            view.statusText = "some status text for section 0"
            return view
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

But you also need to have your header view update a label or some other UI component when `statusText` is changed.

```
class ProfileHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    public var statusText: String? {
        didSet {
            someLabel.text = statusText // update the UI as needed
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I haven't used `didSet` that much so didn't think of it as a solution! It worked :)

Comment: @Philipp - just a side note... that's exactly what I did in the example I showed you in your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77261827/6257435 :)

Comment: @DonMag Sorry I missed it! Thank you once again :)